# Get all points from pointcloud where pointcloud is new Potree.PointCloudOctree(geometry)

Tags: point-cloud, potree

I use potree to view my model I want to get list of all points in pointcloud to add event to each point depending on its index. Can I get list of all points without using measurement tools?

```
Potree.loadPointCloud(cloudPointsPath, "name", e => {
                var pointcloud = e.pointcloud;
                var material = pointcloud.material;
                viewer.scene.addPointCloud(pointcloud);
                material.pointColorType = Potree.PointColorType.RGB;
                material.size = 1;
                material.pointSizeType = Potree.PointSizeType.FIXED;
                material.shape = Potree.PointShape.PARABOLOI;
                viewer.fitToScreen();
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got list of visible points using this function

```
function getAllPointsOfPointCloud(pointCloud) {
        var list = [];
        var array = pointCloud.pcoGeometry.root.geometry.attributes.position.array;
        var index = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < pointCloud.pcoGeometry.root.geometry.attributes.position.length;i=i+3) {
            var x = array[i + 0];
            var y = array[i+ 1];
            var z = array[i + 2];
            let position = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
            position.applyMatrix4(pointCloud.matrixWorld);
            list[index] = position;
            index++;
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: I know this is a few years old, but doesnt this code return all the visible points from the root node only? The root node keeps a very low resolution of the whole point cloud, only a fraction of the total count is shown on screen. As you zoom-in and you get closer to the scene, any ideas how to return the visible points for that zoom level?